# Access array within an array of JSON response in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to access an array response within array this is how I'm getting the friends array successfully

```
let url = URL(string: "http://xyz/api/get-friends-in-meetings")

AF.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        let responseValue = response.value as! NSDictionary
        let friends: [NSDictionary] = responseValue["friends"] as! [NSDictionary]
        //here I want to store the "meeting array so that I can use it later"
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        break
    }
}
```

This is the JSON response

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Friends found.",
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "XYZ",
            "email": "Z@Y.Z",
            
            "meetings": [
                {
                    
                    "meeting_with": "X",
                    "meeting_person_screen_name": "Y",
                    "meeting_purpose": "Z",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

how do I get the "meetings" array which is within the "friends" array? I have tried the same way as I did for friends but it show an error **No exact matches in call to subscript**

Comment: Hi, can you post the complete json?

Comment: @Ladd.c please check now

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define these structs:

```
struct DataResult : Decodable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let friends: [FriendsResult]
}

struct FriendsResult : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let meetings: [MeetingsResult]
}

struct MeetingsResult: Decodable {
    let meeting_with: String
    let meeting_person_screen_name: String
    let meeting_purpose: String
}
```

So after that we need the JSON Example:

```
// Meetings
let meeting1: [String: Any] = [
    "meeting_with": "X",
    "meeting_person_screen_name": "Y",
    "meeting_purpose": "Z"
]

// Friends
let friend1: [String: Any] = [
    "id" : 24,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "email": "x@y.z",
    "meetings": [meeting1]
]

let friend2: [String: Any] = [
    "id" : 25,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "jd@x.doe",
    "meetings": [meeting1]
]

// Main JSON
let jsonExample: [String : Any] = [
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Friends found.",
    "friends": [friend1, friend2]
]
```

Well, we continue to validate the JSON and decode to "DataResult":

```
let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonExample)
        
if valid {
    do {
        let dataResult = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonExample, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        let dataDecode = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataResult.self, from: dataResult)
        let jsonString = String(data: dataResult, encoding: .utf8)
        
        print("JSON: \(String(describing: jsonString))")
        
        if dataDecode.friends.count > 0 {
            // Get first friend you should use guard
            let friend = dataDecode.friends[0]
            let meeting = friend.meetings[0]
            
            print("\(friend.name)")
            print("\(meeting.meeting_with)")
        }
    }
    catch let error {
        print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
else {
    print("Invalid JSON")
}
```